# extra characters "??" get added to the file name when i try creating a text file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a text file with unique names depending upon the `id`value 
My code is

```
with open('USER_LIST', "r") as file:
    for core_id in file:
        filename = "%s.txt" %core_id
        with open(filename, "w") as file:
            subprocess.Popen("query where coreid=%s"%core_id, stdout=file , shell=True)
```

The file `USER_LIST` is a text file that contains a list of user id's. I want to run a command for individual id and store the result in a text file

Here when the text file gets created it gets created as `id??.txt` for e.g. `abc123??.txt`
I am not sure from where are these `??` getting added in my file names.
How to fix this?

Comment: Note you are opening two files as `file`. I'd change the name of the first one to something else

Comment: What is `core_id`'s value if you print it before assigning it to `filename`?

Comment: Probably some unknown character coming from your first file that you read. Maybe its the \n at the end of all your file's lines

Comment: Try copying a few ids into an array and using it instead of your file - this way you can narrow down where the problem is coming from. I expect its to do with characters from your USER_LIST file.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider stripping line endings from lines being read:

```
for core_id in file:
    filename = "%s.txt" % core_id.strip()
```

Second, **don't override** `file` variable in second `with`-statement. Rename `file` to `infile` and `outfile` for example.